# JavaScript Algorithm - Get the object with most similar area in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I have the following object

```
const originalObject = {
   width: 1090,
   height: 723,
}
```

And this list of objects

```
const validObjects = [
   { 
       width: 1080,
       height: 1080
   }, 
   {
       width: 1080,
       height: 1350 
   },
   {
       width: 1080,
       height: 750
   }
]
```

Giving the following helper

```
const area = (width, height) => width * height;
```

I need to find the object from `validObjects` whose area most closely resembles that of the original object.

So if I do:

```
getMostSimilarObject(originalObject, validObjects)
```

I get:

```
{
   width: 1080,
   height: 750
}
```

as `area(1080, 750)` is the most close one to `area(1090, 723)`

Any ideas?

Note: In `validObjects`, there will only be around 3 to 10 objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine how "similar" two objects are (we'll call it "score") by summing the positive difference of the two object's `width` and `height` properties.

With this in mind, we can find the object most similar by getting the object with the lowest score in relation to `originalObject`. Simply loop through the list, calculate the score of the object and the item being looped through, and if the score is lower than the lowest recorded so far, replace the object.

The object at the end of the loop is the most "similar" object.

```js
const validObjects = [{
    width: 1080,
    height: 1080
  },
  {
    width: 1080,
    height: 1350
  },
  {
    width: 1080,
    height: 750
  }
]

const originalObject = {
  width: 1090,
  height: 723,
}

function getMostSimilarObject(obj, list) {
  let score;
  let closest;
  list.forEach(e => {
    let objscore = Math.abs(obj.width - e.width) + Math.abs(obj.height - e.height)
    if (!score || objscore < score) {
      score = objscore;
      closest = e;
    }
  })
  return closest;
}

console.log(getMostSimilarObject(originalObject, validObjects))
```

Comment: The objscore calculation can be replaced with the areas positive difference right?

Comment: @Raul Really depends what you mean by "similar". I would not call an object whose `width` and `height` properties were 2 x 10000 similar to one whose `width` and `height` properties were 200 x 100. If you're looking for area similarity though, that would be true.

Comment: Note that by this metric, a `4 x 7` rectangle is `3` units away from a `3 x 9` rectangle but `9` units away from a `9 x 3` one.  This might be what's wanted but there's a good chance this would be an error.  We might consider instead, `let objscore = Math.min(Math.abs(obj.width - e.width) + Math.abs(obj.height - e.height), Math.abs(obj.width - e.height) + Math.abs(obj.height - e.width))`